# drop wakelock in WakefulBroadcastReceiver that does not start a Service

Tags: android, android-intent, android-broadcast, android-wake-lock

I registered a [WakefulBroadcastReceiver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/WakefulBroadcastReceiver.html) that gets called at some time and based on the content of the broadcast decides to start a service to process the intent or not.

My question is: Is there a wakelock registered even if the `startWakefulService` is not called? If so, how do I release the wakelock again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a wakelock registered even if the startWakefulService is not called?

No, there is not, as you can tell by looking at [the `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/master/v4/java/android/support/v4/content/WakefulBroadcastReceiver.java).